Unable to copy unity animation properties from one file to another
I have a character model with 50 animation, all of them will have same properties Like Root Transform Rotation, Root Transform Position (Y), Root Transform Position (XZ), but i can not see any option to copy paste those properties and doing it manually will take entire day, is there any simple solution to this?
I also tried using editor script but that is also not working.

I was trying to find any option to copy properties but unable to find one

I also tried using editor script but that is also not working. .. what exactly did you try? And what exactly do you have to copy?

I think in general you can do this directly in the .meta file of your imported model .. not beautiful but there are those clips and their root motion settings stored
